# Why were the phase currents taken instead of voltage as inputs in the space vector moduation method?

Tags: three-phase, vector-control

Why is it that the currents (ia,ib,ic) are taken as inputs, instead of voltages (va,vb,vc), when at the end, you need to create 3 phase stator voltages for the rotor to catch up with?

Comment: Current is what produces magnetic fields which is what the rotor catches up with, not voltage.

Comment: If currents are used as input that's because you are using currents loops to control the motor ? FOC ? Otherwise a SVM only needs stator position and the strength of your voltage vector to compute PWM's duty cycles.

Comment: Where did you see this? Every instance of FOC+SVPWM I have ever designed always has the phase voltage going into SVPWM because it is the voltage you are wanting to synthesis

Comment: @DKNguyen while current is what produces magnetic fields, it is the applied voltage, the voltage synthesised by SVM which facilitate the current to flow. FOC is always on the current as you are controlling the current. Iabc -> Id,Iq will produce a voltage demand post PI controller. Vd,Vq => Vabc which is fed into the PWM stage, be it SPWM or SVM (ie SVPWM). I think the OP has misread something.

Comment: @JonRB , I’m probably confused as I’m a newbie here. https://www.switchcraft.org/learning/2016/12/16/vector-control-for-dummies, this was my reference and in the overview link in the article, the three phase currents were taken as input to Clark transformation block and that is why I thought why current is taken as input.Just feel free to rectify me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: @rookie91. https://uk.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/ref/inductionmachinedirecttorquecontrolwithspacevectormodulator.html the point of SVM (or SVPWM) is to synthesis an output waveform based upon an input waveform and a supply. The SVM is supplied with voltage for a voltage source inverter thus it chops this to synthesis an incoming demand. This demand must be voltage otherwise how can you feed in current and produce voltage out. That isn't what SVM does. So either that site is wrong or they have didn't include the current to voltage demand conversion.

Comment: @JonRB  thanks a lot for the valuable inputs and I’ve good clarity now on this.

Comment: @rookie91 no problem. Basically SVM is a modulator block so if what is being chopped is voltage the input must be voltage. It could be current if it is a current source inverter (but that site isn't).  You want to modulate the voltage to force current to flow to then measure the current to correct your modulation. What I want to know is why there is so many upvotes for the wrong comments and wrong answer....

Answer (score 0):

Because what's important are the currents not the voltages. You do adjust current by voltage control. The current  VS. voltage has a phase delay.

You do have a current setpoint and measured current, you do adjust PWM duty cycle to bring up voltage so that the setpoint current will flow through motor winding.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx09Tx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The OP is talking about the input to SVM. The OP is incorrect and this reply is only confusing things further. The SVM block in your diagram is the PWM block who's input is V_set and the output is V. This is in alignment with my comment to the OP. The OP must be confusing an entire control loop which includes a FOC.